# Why does the Angular CLI opens my website on HTTPS

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have created an Angular 10 project in Visual studio code but when I run the command; `$ ng serve --open` it opens `https://localhost:4200/` in Google Chrome but it shows the following error `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

However, in the Angular CLI it shows `http://localhost:4200/`. Why is my browser using the HTTPS protocol and not HTTP?

When I clear my browser history, clear temp and then restart my machine it works properly on `http://localhost:4200/`. But after some time it starts running on `https://localhost:4200/` and fails to load application with same error `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

Any idea if I have to change any browser settings or I have to add any configuration in code?

> Note: I am running my Web API in another Visual Studio code on locally which I am calling from my angular app. It also shows the same error sometimes.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: heres yours answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891619/intermittent-err-ssl-protocol-error-error-for-cross-domain-request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intermittent ERR\_SSL\_PROTOCOL\_ERROR error for cross domain request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891619/intermittent-err-ssl-protocol-error-error-for-cross-domain-request)

Comment: Thank for your reply @Giannis and Daniel but no help from above links , it did not solve my issue, its not intermittent issue for service call. It is happening as soon as I run command 'ng serve --open' where I don't have any service call but just loading Login page

Comment: I think I am the only one facing this issue

Comment: I have the same problem, any news?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the urls in launch.json in your .vscode directory.